# Uniform continuity of a specific function

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, matrix-calculus, uniform-continuity

Is the function
$f(a,A)\triangleq \frac{A^{-1}a}{\sqrt{a^{\star}Aa}}$ uniformly continuous?  Where $a$ is a $d$-dimensional vector and $A$ is an invertible $d\times d$-matrix.

I tried to prove it but I can't get anything past pointwise... is it wrong?

Comment: What is $a^\star$?

Comment: the transpose of a

Comment: So the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R^d\times\Bbb R^{d^2}$?

Comment: no its $\mathbb{R}^d \times GL_D(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @CSA Then the domain of $f$ is a bit complex, right? Because sometimes $a^\star Aa=0$, even when $a\neq0$ and $A$ is invertible.

Comment: I mean is it uniformly continous on its domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't.

Take $d=1$ and consider just the matrices with determinant greater than $0$. Then we are talking about the function$$\begin{array}{cccl}\mathbb{R}\times(0,+\infty)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\(a,b)&\mapsto&\frac{a/b}{\sqrt{aba}}&=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(a)}{b\sqrt{b}},\end{array}$$which is not uniformly continuous.